# Ways to fill up a $4 \times 4$ matrix with numbers $1$ to $16$, s.t its rank is $1$ under modulo $17$

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

As the title suggest. How many ways are there to fill up a $4 \times 4$ matrix with numbers $1$ to $16$, so that its rank is $1$ under modulo $17$ (i.e. consider elements of the matrix under $Z_{17}$)

Rank being 1 basically means all rows or columns are linearly dependent. If we look at a simple case, $2 \times 2$ matrix with numbers $1$ to $4$, under modulo $5$, all I can find is

\begin{matrix}
1 & 4\\
3 & 2
\end{matrix}

and its rotations. But I am not sure how to generalize this to higher orders..

Comment: Doesn't rank 1 mean linearly dependant? If it's linearly independent, it's a full rank matrix

Comment: Hence the columns have to have the same ratio

Comment: rank would be integer from 1 to 4. If rank is 1 modulo 17, the rank is 1.

Comment: @dust05: The question is imprecisely formulated. As the example illustrates, the intention is not to consider the residue of the rank modulo $17$, but to consider the elements of the matrix as elements of $\mathbb Z_{17}$.

Comment: aha. now i seee.

Comment: The expression "all rows or columns are linearly dependent" is not well-defined. If we'd take it to mean "the rows or columns are linearly dependent", it would be equivalent to the rank not being full, not to the rank being $1$. "Each pair of rows or columns is linearly dependent" is equivalent to the rank being $1$.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a python script to find them by brute force.  The matrices all have $1$ in the first row and first column, and the entries in both the first row and first column are in increasing order (viewing them temporarily as elements of $\mathbb{Z}$.)  I found $256$ such matrices.  Of course, the rows and columns can each be permuted without changing the rank, so each matrix represents $24^2$ matrices.

I don't see any patterns at all.  $256=16^2$ gives one hope, but for me, at least, it's an empty promise.  Because of that, I'm appending a list of all $256$ matrices.  Maybe you'll see something I don't.

In the listing below, the matrices have been flattened for typographical considerations, so the first line represents the matrix, $$\begin{bmatrix}
1  &2  &3  &6\\  
4  &8 &12  &7\\
13 &9  &5 &10\\
16 &15 &14 &11\end{bmatrix}$$

```
[ 1  2  3  6  4  8 12  7 13  9  5 10 16 15 14 11]
[ 1  2  3  7  4  8 12 11 13  9  5  6 16 15 14 10]
[ 1  2  3 10  4  8 12  6 13  9  5 11 16 15 14  7]
[ 1  2  3 11  4  8 12 10 13  9  5  7 16 15 14  6]
[ 1  2  4  8  3  6 12  7 14 11  5 10 16 15 13  9]
[ 1  2  4  8  5 10  3  6 12  7 14 11 16 15 13  9]
[ 1  2  4  8  6 12  7 14 11  5 10  3 16 15 13  9]
[ 1  2  4  8  7 14 11  5 10  3  6 12 16 15 13  9]
[ 1  2  4  9  3  6 12 10 14 11  5  7 16 15 13  8]
[ 1  2  4  9  5 10  3 11 12  7 14  6 16 15 13  8]
[ 1  2  4  9  6 12  7  3 11  5 10 14 16 15 13  8]
[ 1  2  4  9  7 14 11 12 10  3  6  5 16 15 13  8]
[ 1  2  5  6  4  8  3  7 13  9 14 10 16 15 12 11]
[ 1  2  5  7  4  8  3 11 13  9 14  6 16 15 12 10]
[ 1  2  5 10  4  8  3  6 13  9 14 11 16 15 12  7]
[ 1  2  5 11  4  8  3 10 13  9 14  7 16 15 12  6]

[ 1  2  6 12  4  8  7 14 13  9 10  3 16 15 11  5]
[ 1  2  6 14  4  8  7  5 13  9 10 12 16 15 11  3]
[ 1  2  7 12  4  8 11 14 13  9  6  3 16 15 10  5]
[ 1  2  7 14  4  8 11  5 13  9  6 12 16 15 10  3]
[ 1  2  8 13  3  6  7  5 14 11 10 12 16 15  9  4]
[ 1  2  8 13  5 10  6 14 12  7 11  3 16 15  9  4]
[ 1  2  8 13  6 12 14 10 11  5  3  7 16 15  9  4]
[ 1  2  8 13  7 14  5  6 10  3 12 11 16 15  9  4]
[ 1  2  9 13  3  6 10  5 14 11  7 12 16 15  8  4]
[ 1  2  9 13  5 10 11 14 12  7  6  3 16 15  8  4]
[ 1  2  9 13  6 12  3 10 11  5 14  7 16 15  8  4]
[ 1  2  9 13  7 14 12  6 10  3  5 11 16 15  8  4]
[ 1  2 10 12  4  8  6 14 13  9 11  3 16 15  7  5]
[ 1  2 10 14  4  8  6  5 13  9 11 12 16 15  7  3]
[ 1  2 11 12  4  8 10 14 13  9  7  3 16 15  6  5]
[ 1  2 11 14  4  8 10  5 13  9  7 12 16 15  6  3]

[ 1  2 15 16  3  6 11 14  4  8  9 13  5 10  7 12]
[ 1  2 15 16  3  6 11 14  4  8  9 13 12  7 10  5]
[ 1  2 15 16  3  6 11 14  5 10  7 12 13  9  8  4]
[ 1  2 15 16  3  6 11 14 12  7 10  5 13  9  8  4]
[ 1  2 15 16  4  8  9 13  5 10  7 12 14 11  6  3]
[ 1  2 15 16  4  8  9 13  6 12  5 11  7 14  3 10]
[ 1  2 15 16  4  8  9 13  6 12  5 11 10  3 14  7]
[ 1  2 15 16  4  8  9 13  7 14  3 10 11  5 12  6]
[ 1  2 15 16  4  8  9 13 10  3 14  7 11  5 12  6]
[ 1  2 15 16  4  8  9 13 12  7 10  5 14 11  6  3]
[ 1  2 15 16  5 10  7 12 13  9  8  4 14 11  6  3]
[ 1  2 15 16  6 12  5 11  7 14  3 10 13  9  8  4]
[ 1  2 15 16  6 12  5 11 10  3 14  7 13  9  8  4]
[ 1  2 15 16  7 14  3 10 11  5 12  6 13  9  8  4]
[ 1  2 15 16 10  3 14  7 11  5 12  6 13  9  8  4]
[ 1  2 15 16 12  7 10  5 13  9  8  4 14 11  6  3]

[ 1  3  4  5  2  6  8 10 15 11  9  7 16 14 13 12]
[ 1  3  4  5  8  7 15  6  9 10  2 11 16 14 13 12]
[ 1  3  4 12  2  6  8  7 15 11  9 10 16 14 13  5]
[ 1  3  4 12  8  7 15 11  9 10  2  6 16 14 13  5]
[ 1  3  5 13  2  6 10  9 15 11  7  8 16 14 12  4]
[ 1  3  5 13  8  7  6  2  9 10 11 15 16 14 12  4]
[ 1  3  6  8  4 12  7 15 13  5 10  2 16 14 11  9]
[ 1  3  6  9  4 12  7  2 13  5 10 15 16 14 11  8]
[ 1  3  6 15  4 12  7  9 13  5 10  8 16 14 11  2]
[ 1  3  7  8  4 12 11 15 13  5  6  2 16 14 10  9]
[ 1  3  7  9  4 12 11  2 13  5  6 15 16 14 10  8]
[ 1  3  7 15  4 12 11  9 13  5  6  8 16 14 10  2]
[ 1  3  8 10  4 12 15  6 13  5  2 11 16 14  9  7]
[ 1  3  8 11  4 12 15 10 13  5  2  7 16 14  9  6]
[ 1  3  9 10  4 12  2  6 13  5 15 11 16 14  8  7]
[ 1  3  9 11  4 12  2 10 13  5 15  7 16 14  8  6]

[ 1  3 10 15  4 12  6  9 13  5 11  8 16 14  7  2]
[ 1  3 11 15  4 12 10  9 13  5  7  8 16 14  6  2]
[ 1  3 12 13  2  6  7  9 15 11 10  8 16 14  5  4]
[ 1  3 12 13  8  7 11  2  9 10  6 15 16 14  5  4]
[ 1  3 14 16  2  6 11 15  4 12  5 13  8  7 10  9]
[ 1  3 14 16  2  6 11 15  4 12  5 13  9 10  7  8]
[ 1  3 14 16  2  6 11 15  8  7 10  9 13  5 12  4]
[ 1  3 14 16  2  6 11 15  9 10  7  8 13  5 12  4]
[ 1  3 14 16  4 12  5 13  8  7 10  9 15 11  6  2]
[ 1  3 14 16  4 12  5 13  9 10  7  8 15 11  6  2]
[ 1  3 14 16  8  7 10  9 13  5 12  4 15 11  6  2]
[ 1  3 14 16  9 10  7  8 13  5 12  4 15 11  6  2]
[ 1  4  5 14  2  8 10 11 15  9  7  6 16 13 12  3]
[ 1  4  5 14  8 15  6 10  9  2 11  7 16 13 12  3]
[ 1  4  6  7  2  8 12 14 15  9  5  3 16 13 11 10]
[ 1  4  6  7  8 15 14  5  9  2  3 12 16 13 11 10]

[ 1  4  6 10  2  8 12  3 15  9  5 14 16 13 11  7]
[ 1  4  6 10  8 15 14 12  9  2  3  5 16 13 11  7]
[ 1  4  7 11  2  8 14  5 15  9  3 12 16 13 10  6]
[ 1  4  7 11  8 15  5  3  9  2 12 14 16 13 10  6]
[ 1  4  8 15  3 12  7 11 14  5 10  6 16 13  9  2]
[ 1  4  8 15  5  3  6  7 12 14 11 10 16 13  9  2]
[ 1  4  8 15  6  7 14  5 11 10  3 12 16 13  9  2]
[ 1  4  8 15  7 11  5  3 10  6 12 14 16 13  9  2]
[ 1  4  9 15  3 12 10 11 14  5  7  6 16 13  8  2]
[ 1  4  9 15  5  3 11  7 12 14  6 10 16 13  8  2]
[ 1  4  9 15  6  7  3  5 11 10 14 12 16 13  8  2]
[ 1  4  9 15  7 11 12  3 10  6  5 14 16 13  8  2]
[ 1  4 10 11  2  8  3  5 15  9 14 12 16 13  7  6]
[ 1  4 10 11  8 15 12  3  9  2  5 14 16 13  7  6]
[ 1  4 12 14  2  8  7 11 15  9 10  6 16 13  5  3]
[ 1  4 12 14  8 15 11 10  9  2  6  7 16 13  5  3]

[ 1  4 13 16  2  8  9 15  3 12  5 14  6  7 10 11]
[ 1  4 13 16  2  8  9 15  3 12  5 14  7 11  6 10]
[ 1  4 13 16  2  8  9 15  3 12  5 14 10  6 11  7]
[ 1  4 13 16  2  8  9 15  3 12  5 14 11 10  7  6]
[ 1  4 13 16  2  8  9 15  5  3 14 12  6  7 10 11]
[ 1  4 13 16  2  8  9 15  5  3 14 12  7 11  6 10]
[ 1  4 13 16  2  8  9 15  5  3 14 12 10  6 11  7]
[ 1  4 13 16  2  8  9 15  5  3 14 12 11 10  7  6]
[ 1  4 13 16  2  8  9 15  6  7 10 11 12 14  3  5]
[ 1  4 13 16  2  8  9 15  6  7 10 11 14  5 12  3]
[ 1  4 13 16  2  8  9 15  7 11  6 10 12 14  3  5]
[ 1  4 13 16  2  8  9 15  7 11  6 10 14  5 12  3]
[ 1  4 13 16  2  8  9 15 10  6 11  7 12 14  3  5]
[ 1  4 13 16  2  8  9 15 10  6 11  7 14  5 12  3]
[ 1  4 13 16  2  8  9 15 11 10  7  6 12 14  3  5]
[ 1  4 13 16  2  8  9 15 11 10  7  6 14  5 12  3]

[ 1  4 13 16  3 12  5 14  6  7 10 11  8 15  2  9]
[ 1  4 13 16  3 12  5 14  6  7 10 11  9  2 15  8]
[ 1  4 13 16  3 12  5 14  6  7 10 11 15  9  8  2]
[ 1  4 13 16  3 12  5 14  7 11  6 10  8 15  2  9]
[ 1  4 13 16  3 12  5 14  7 11  6 10  9  2 15  8]
[ 1  4 13 16  3 12  5 14  7 11  6 10 15  9  8  2]
[ 1  4 13 16  3 12  5 14  8 15  2  9 10  6 11  7]
[ 1  4 13 16  3 12  5 14  8 15  2  9 11 10  7  6]
[ 1  4 13 16  3 12  5 14  9  2 15  8 10  6 11  7]
[ 1  4 13 16  3 12  5 14  9  2 15  8 11 10  7  6]
[ 1  4 13 16  3 12  5 14 10  6 11  7 15  9  8  2]
[ 1  4 13 16  3 12  5 14 11 10  7  6 15  9  8  2]
[ 1  4 13 16  5  3 14 12  6  7 10 11  8 15  2  9]
[ 1  4 13 16  5  3 14 12  6  7 10 11  9  2 15  8]
[ 1  4 13 16  5  3 14 12  6  7 10 11 15  9  8  2]
[ 1  4 13 16  5  3 14 12  7 11  6 10  8 15  2  9]

[ 1  4 13 16  5  3 14 12  7 11  6 10  9  2 15  8]
[ 1  4 13 16  5  3 14 12  7 11  6 10 15  9  8  2]
[ 1  4 13 16  5  3 14 12  8 15  2  9 10  6 11  7]
[ 1  4 13 16  5  3 14 12  8 15  2  9 11 10  7  6]
[ 1  4 13 16  5  3 14 12  9  2 15  8 10  6 11  7]
[ 1  4 13 16  5  3 14 12  9  2 15  8 11 10  7  6]
[ 1  4 13 16  5  3 14 12 10  6 11  7 15  9  8  2]
[ 1  4 13 16  5  3 14 12 11 10  7  6 15  9  8  2]
[ 1  4 13 16  6  7 10 11  8 15  2  9 12 14  3  5]
[ 1  4 13 16  6  7 10 11  8 15  2  9 14  5 12  3]
[ 1  4 13 16  6  7 10 11  9  2 15  8 12 14  3  5]
[ 1  4 13 16  6  7 10 11  9  2 15  8 14  5 12  3]
[ 1  4 13 16  6  7 10 11 12 14  3  5 15  9  8  2]
[ 1  4 13 16  6  7 10 11 14  5 12  3 15  9  8  2]
[ 1  4 13 16  7 11  6 10  8 15  2  9 12 14  3  5]
[ 1  4 13 16  7 11  6 10  8 15  2  9 14  5 12  3]

[ 1  4 13 16  7 11  6 10  9  2 15  8 12 14  3  5]
[ 1  4 13 16  7 11  6 10  9  2 15  8 14  5 12  3]
[ 1  4 13 16  7 11  6 10 12 14  3  5 15  9  8  2]
[ 1  4 13 16  7 11  6 10 14  5 12  3 15  9  8  2]
[ 1  4 13 16  8 15  2  9 10  6 11  7 12 14  3  5]
[ 1  4 13 16  8 15  2  9 10  6 11  7 14  5 12  3]
[ 1  4 13 16  8 15  2  9 11 10  7  6 12 14  3  5]
[ 1  4 13 16  8 15  2  9 11 10  7  6 14  5 12  3]
[ 1  4 13 16  9  2 15  8 10  6 11  7 12 14  3  5]
[ 1  4 13 16  9  2 15  8 10  6 11  7 14  5 12  3]
[ 1  4 13 16  9  2 15  8 11 10  7  6 12 14  3  5]
[ 1  4 13 16  9  2 15  8 11 10  7  6 14  5 12  3]
[ 1  4 13 16 10  6 11  7 12 14  3  5 15  9  8  2]
[ 1  4 13 16 10  6 11  7 14  5 12  3 15  9  8  2]
[ 1  4 13 16 11 10  7  6 12 14  3  5 15  9  8  2]
[ 1  4 13 16 11 10  7  6 14  5 12  3 15  9  8  2]

[ 1  5  6  8  4  3  7 15 13 14 10  2 16 12 11  9]
[ 1  5  6  9  4  3  7  2 13 14 10 15 16 12 11  8]
[ 1  5  6 15  4  3  7  9 13 14 10  8 16 12 11  2]
[ 1  5  7  8  4  3 11 15 13 14  6  2 16 12 10  9]
[ 1  5  7  9  4  3 11  2 13 14  6 15 16 12 10  8]
[ 1  5  7 15  4  3 11  9 13 14  6  8 16 12 10  2]
[ 1  5  8 10  4  3 15  6 13 14  2 11 16 12  9  7]
[ 1  5  8 11  4  3 15 10 13 14  2  7 16 12  9  6]
[ 1  5  9 10  4  3  2  6 13 14 15 11 16 12  8  7]
[ 1  5  9 11  4  3  2 10 13 14 15  7 16 12  8  6]
[ 1  5 10 15  4  3  6  9 13 14 11  8 16 12  7  2]
[ 1  5 11 15  4  3 10  9 13 14  7  8 16 12  6  2]
[ 1  5 12 16  2 10  7 15  4  3 14 13  8  6 11  9]
[ 1  5 12 16  2 10  7 15  4  3 14 13  9 11  6  8]
[ 1  5 12 16  2 10  7 15  8  6 11  9 13 14  3  4]
[ 1  5 12 16  2 10  7 15  9 11  6  8 13 14  3  4]

[ 1  5 12 16  4  3 14 13  8  6 11  9 15  7 10  2]
[ 1  5 12 16  4  3 14 13  9 11  6  8 15  7 10  2]
[ 1  5 12 16  8  6 11  9 13 14  3  4 15  7 10  2]
[ 1  5 12 16  9 11  6  8 13 14  3  4 15  7 10  2]
[ 1  5 13 14  2 10  9 11 15  7  8  6 16 12  4  3]
[ 1  5 13 14  8  6  2 10  9 11 15  7 16 12  4  3]
[ 1  6  7 13  2 12 14  9 15  5  3  8 16 11 10  4]
[ 1  6  7 13  8 14  5  2  9  3 12 15 16 11 10  4]
[ 1  6  8 12  4  7 15 14 13 10  2  3 16 11  9  5]
[ 1  6  8 14  4  7 15  5 13 10  2 12 16 11  9  3]
[ 1  6  9 12  4  7  2 14 13 10 15  3 16 11  8  5]
[ 1  6  9 14  4  7  2  5 13 10 15 12 16 11  8  3]
[ 1  6 10 13  2 12  3  9 15  5 14  8 16 11  7  4]
[ 1  6 10 13  8 14 12  2  9  3  5 15 16 11  7  4]
[ 1  6 11 16  2 12  5 15  4  7 10 13  8 14  3  9]
[ 1  6 11 16  2 12  5 15  4  7 10 13  9  3 14  8]

[ 1  6 11 16  2 12  5 15  8 14  3  9 13 10  7  4]
[ 1  6 11 16  2 12  5 15  9  3 14  8 13 10  7  4]
[ 1  6 11 16  4  7 10 13  8 14  3  9 15  5 12  2]
[ 1  6 11 16  4  7 10 13  9  3 14  8 15  5 12  2]
[ 1  6 11 16  8 14  3  9 13 10  7  4 15  5 12  2]
[ 1  6 11 16  9  3 14  8 13 10  7  4 15  5 12  2]
[ 1  6 12 15  4  7 14  9 13 10  3  8 16 11  5  2]
[ 1  6 14 15  4  7  5  9 13 10 12  8 16 11  3  2]
[ 1  7  8 12  4 11 15 14 13  6  2  3 16 10  9  5]
[ 1  7  8 14  4 11 15  5 13  6  2 12 16 10  9  3]
[ 1  7  9 12  4 11  2 14 13  6 15  3 16 10  8  5]
[ 1  7  9 14  4 11  2  5 13  6 15 12 16 10  8  3]
[ 1  7 10 16  2 14  3 15  4 11  6 13  8  5 12  9]
[ 1  7 10 16  2 14  3 15  4 11  6 13  9 12  5  8]
[ 1  7 10 16  2 14  3 15  8  5 12  9 13  6 11  4]
[ 1  7 10 16  2 14  3 15  9 12  5  8 13  6 11  4]

[ 1  7 10 16  4 11  6 13  8  5 12  9 15  3 14  2]
[ 1  7 10 16  4 11  6 13  9 12  5  8 15  3 14  2]
[ 1  7 10 16  8  5 12  9 13  6 11  4 15  3 14  2]
[ 1  7 10 16  9 12  5  8 13  6 11  4 15  3 14  2]
[ 1  7 11 13  2 14  5  9 15  3 12  8 16 10  6  4]
[ 1  7 11 13  8  5  3  2  9 12 14 15 16 10  6  4]
[ 1  7 12 15  4 11 14  9 13  6  3  8 16 10  5  2]
[ 1  7 14 15  4 11  5  9 13  6 12  8 16 10  3  2]
[ 1  8  9 16  3  7 10 14  4 15  2 13  5  6 11 12]
[ 1  8  9 16  3  7 10 14  4 15  2 13 12 11  6  5]
[ 1  8  9 16  3  7 10 14  5  6 11 12 13  2 15  4]
[ 1  8  9 16  3  7 10 14 12 11  6  5 13  2 15  4]
[ 1  8  9 16  4 15  2 13  5  6 11 12 14 10  7  3]
[ 1  8  9 16  4 15  2 13  6 14  3 11  7  5 12 10]
[ 1  8  9 16  4 15  2 13  6 14  3 11 10 12  5  7]
[ 1  8  9 16  4 15  2 13  7  5 12 10 11  3 14  6]

[ 1  8  9 16  4 15  2 13 10 12  5  7 11  3 14  6]
[ 1  8  9 16  4 15  2 13 12 11  6  5 14 10  7  3]
[ 1  8  9 16  5  6 11 12 13  2 15  4 14 10  7  3]
[ 1  8  9 16  6 14  3 11  7  5 12 10 13  2 15  4]
[ 1  8  9 16  6 14  3 11 10 12  5  7 13  2 15  4]
[ 1  8  9 16  7  5 12 10 11  3 14  6 13  2 15  4]
[ 1  8  9 16 10 12  5  7 11  3 14  6 13  2 15  4]
[ 1  8  9 16 12 11  6  5 13  2 15  4 14 10  7  3]
[ 1  8 10 12  4 15  6 14 13  2 11  3 16  9  7  5]
[ 1  8 10 14  4 15  6  5 13  2 11 12 16  9  7  3]
[ 1  8 11 12  4 15 10 14 13  2  7  3 16  9  6  5]
[ 1  8 11 14  4 15 10  5 13  2  7 12 16  9  6  3]
[ 1  8 13 15  3  7  5 11 14 10 12  6 16  9  4  2]
[ 1  8 13 15  5  6 14  7 12 11  3 10 16  9  4  2]
[ 1  8 13 15  6 14 10  5 11  3  7 12 16  9  4  2]
[ 1  8 13 15  7  5  6  3 10 12 11 14 16  9  4  2]

[ 1  9 10 12  4  2  6 14 13 15 11  3 16  8  7  5]
[ 1  9 10 14  4  2  6  5 13 15 11 12 16  8  7  3]
[ 1  9 11 12  4  2 10 14 13 15  7  3 16  8  6  5]
[ 1  9 11 14  4  2 10  5 13 15  7 12 16  8  6  3]
[ 1  9 13 15  3 10  5 11 14  7 12  6 16  8  4  2]
[ 1  9 13 15  5 11 14  7 12  6  3 10 16  8  4  2]
[ 1  9 13 15  6  3 10  5 11 14  7 12 16  8  4  2]
[ 1  9 13 15  7 12  6  3 10  5 11 14 16  8  4  2]
[ 1 10 11 13  2  3  5  9 15 14 12  8 16  7  6  4]
[ 1 10 11 13  8 12  3  2  9  5 14 15 16  7  6  4]
[ 1 10 12 15  4  6 14  9 13 11  3  8 16  7  5  2]
[ 1 10 14 15  4  6  5  9 13 11 12  8 16  7  3  2]
[ 1 11 12 15  4 10 14  9 13  7  3  8 16  6  5  2]
[ 1 11 14 15  4 10  5  9 13  7 12  8 16  6  3  2]
[ 1 12 13 14  2  7  9 11 15 10  8  6 16  5  4  3]
[ 1 12 13 14  8 11  2 10  9  6 15  7 16  5  4  3]
```

Comment: Of course you can multiply each matrix by any non-zero scalar factor to get another rank 1 matrix. This may well reduce the number of essentially different matrices to just 16. Then there is 90 degree rotation that may reduce it by another factor 2 (horizontal/vertical reflection can be done by permuting the rows or columns, so the other symmetries of the square are already taken care of). Of course some solutions may have some symmetry, so it might not reduce quite as much.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis They each have $a_{11}=1$ so scalar multiplication would not reduce the number.  The same goes for symmetries of the square, except reflection in the main diagonal.  I thought about that, but I was reluctant to identify a matrix with its transpose.

Comment: But after you do the scalar multiplication, and then permute the rows/columns so that 1 is at the top left and the first row/column is sorted, then you may get one of the others on your list, making them essentially the same. By the way, I wrote a program to do this, and I think you're still left with 48 essentially distinct matrices.